# loop through two dataframes and plot by column in loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, plot

I have 2 dataframes with the same column names, index and size.  I want to create a scatterplot of one dataframe column vs the other with the same header.  When I try the code below, only the sim.columns are looping, while the obs.columns plots only the first column and don't loop. So what I get are scatter plots of each sim.columns against the first obs.column only.  I'm not sure what is messed up with this loop.   Thanks for your help!

```
    obs= pd.read_csv(obsFile)
    obs.rename(columns={obs.columns[0]: "SP" }, inplace = True)
    sim= pd.read_csv(simFile)
    sim.rename(columns={sim.columns[0]: "SP" }, inplace = True)
    
sim = sim.set_index("SP")
obs = obs.set_index("SP")

for colsim in sim.columns:
    for colobs in obs.columns:
        axes = plt.gca()
        axes.set_xlim([1,630])
        plt.scatter(sim.index, sim[colsim])
        plt.scatter(obs.index, obs[colobs])

        plt.xlabel('Stress Period')
        plt.ylabel('groundwater elevation(m)')
        plt.title(str(colsim))
        plt.savefig(os.path.join(outFold, str(colsim)+'.pdf')) 
        plt.close()
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a double for loop:

```
for colsim in sim.columns:
    for colobs in obs.columns:
        ...
```

Just use a `zip`:

```
for colsim, colobs in zip(sim.columns, obs.columns):
    ...
```

Not sure what you mean with what you wanna do, but if this code doesn't work, try removing the `break` then it should work, but if it works without removing the break just keep it.

Comment: zip is different from double loop ~

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a nested loop here, it does not what you want to achieve. Instead you want to loop through both dataframes at the same time in one loop. i can think of 2 ways how to achieve this:

1. merge the dataframes and loop through the merged dataframe in one loop
2. introduce a counter variable which can be used as an index for looping through both dataframes parallel

Comment: Just using `zip` is enough... Like in my answer

Comment: you are right, i used the wrong term. by merging i meant zipping.